# How to do comparison of two columns from different dataframe efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

There is two table one is daily market price of commodity, another is purchase report. Now i want to compare market price and sales price how can i do efficiently

market_price

```
date,commodity,price
2008-12-01,akfuh3,850
2008-12-02,akfuh3,1034
2008-12-03,akfuh3,1220
2008-12-05,akfuh3,1000
```

purches_report

```
date,dealer,commodity,sale_price
2008-12-01,ABC,akfuh3,850
2008-12-01,XYZ,akfuh3,855
2008-12-02,ABC,akfuh3,900
2008-12-03,ABC,akfuh3,1300
2008-12-03,XYZ,akfuh3,1300
2008-12-05,PQR,akfuh3,1050
```

I merge both and than compare it both columns but it will take more memory as there can be multiple purchase per date and it will make multiple copy of sale_price for each date.

```
full_report = pd.merge(report, mrkt.drop("commodity",1), on="date")
sale_price_higher_than_market = full_report.sale_price > full_report.price
```

Comment: You are doing it correctly. There is no problem with that. @anonymous

Comment: If i have larger dataframe than it will make dataframe size bigger so if there any another way...  like iterating or using map with lambda something like that

Comment: This is the most efficient way and one `int` column wouldn't cause you much trouble on the memory side of it.

Comment: all right. thank you.